# How to write Python Function that returns Values as Parameters in Second Function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am trying to write two functions, where the first func takes in three integers, squares them, and the second function takes those values and sums the squared numbers. For some reason, I cannot get the idea of using parameters to mentally click. My code is a mess, but here's what I currently have:

```
def squareEach(num1, num2, num3): #return three values, each squared
    num1,num2,num3=eval(input("Enter three integers: ")).split
    sq1=num1**2
    sq2=num2**2
    sq3=num3**2
    return sq1, sq2, sq3

def sumList(num1, num2, num3): #sums the squared nums from first func
    n1, n2, n3=squareEach(num1, num2, num3).split
    sum=n1+n2+n3
    return sum

squareEach(num1,num2,num3)
```

However, when I run the code and call sqaureEach(), I get an error message telling me the formal parameters in squareEach() are not "defined." How do I have the actual parameters created from the input assigned to num1, num2, num3?

Comment: Please share your code till now

Comment: you have to use `return values` to return values and then you can use them as arguments in other functions.

Comment: My apologies--I accidentally published my question before I had put my code in. I just finished updating my question.

Comment: In your code it's not clear whether `squareEach` should take parameters or user input. You seem to be doing both. If it takes parameters you would call it it with values: `squareEach(2, 3, 4)` and not ask for user input. If you want the function to ask for input, you don't need the parameters.

Comment: `a,b,c=squareEach(num1,num2,num3)`  `result = sumList(a, b, c)`

Comment: if you get values as parameters then don't use `input()`

Comment: first you forgot `()` in both `split()`. Second: you don't use `split()` with `squareEach().split()` because you returns  tuple with 3 values, not string.

Comment: thank you all! I understand that using parameters and asking for user inputs is redundant, but I am working on this question in preparation for an exam, and the prof specified that we do both (??), which completely confused me.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why is there an `eval()` in there? The `split()` is also missing parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have Understand

```
def squareEach(num1, num2, num3): #return three values, each squared

    sq1=num1**2
    sq2=num2**2
    sq3=num3**2
    return sq1, sq2, sq3

def sumList(lst): #sums the squared nums from first func
    return sum(lst)

num1,num2,num3=eval(input("Enter three integers: "))
square=squareEach(num1,num2,num3) 
sum_of_Squared=sumList(square)
print(sum_of_Squared)
```

output

```
Enter three integers:  2,3,4
29
```

And if you want create generic function for any no of element  try following

```
def sumList(*lst):
    return sum(map(lambda a:a**2,lst[0]))

sum_of_Squared=sumList(eval(input("Enter three integers: ")))
print(sum_of_Squared)
```

output

```
Enter three integers:  2,3,4
29
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def squareEach():
    "Gets 3 inputs"
    nums = input("Enter three or more integers separated by comma: ")
    nums = nums.split(",")
    nums = [int(x)**2 for x in nums]
    return nums


nums = squareEach()
somma = sum(nums)
print(somma)
```

[image]